# How to add a space after a point?

Tags: php, regex

I'd like to add a space after any point found with an alphabetic or numeric character just after it (no space found), assuming the next character after the point is not an end of line (cr, lf, ...) character.

`preg_replace` `"/.[a-z0-9]{1}/"` with `"/. [a-z0-9]/i"`

How may I do this in PHP ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
$str = preg_replace("/\.(?=[a-z\d])/i", ". ", $str);
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/ilK2hN9y)

Comment: I've read the doc but it's a little bit hard to understand. Would this `"#(?=[a-zA-Z\d])[:]#"` allow me to find any : with an alphabetic or numeric character just behind it ? It does not seem to work.

Comment: No, this would match nothing.  Lookaheads and -behinds match *positions*, not characters. So in this case it would match any position with a following alphanumerical character. But the colon is not an alphanumeric character, so the overall expression does not match. You would need: `#:(?=[a-zA-Z\d])#`. This matches a colon, only if the following character is alphanumeric. Lookaheads and -behinds can be a bit tricky to understand, so don't worry if it takes some time to get your head around it.

Comment: So how may I do to test the charater that is just before the : one ?

Comment: You can use a *positive lookbehind*:  `#(?<=[a-zA-Z\d]):#` but in PHP they have to have a fixed length afaik (so you cannot use quantifiers such as `+` or `*`). And of course you can always omit lookarounds and use capture groups instead (in most cases I think).

Answer (score 2):

You already posted the almost correct answer

```
$text = preg_replace( '#\.([A-Za-z0-9])#', '. $1', $text );
```

should do the trick